# cant connect from my desktop to rabbitmq on ec2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, telnet

I am trying to create an ubuntu vm with rabbitmq on EC2.
I can telnet my rabbit but cant connect with java client.

Here is my code

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("172.31.4.61");
factory.setPort(5672);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

I get the following

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you add a rule to [allow inbound traffic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) for port 5672 in the EC2 Security Group.